# GSuite: how to change authenticator device?

Tags: g-suite, google-authenticator, two-factor-authentication

I'm GSuite admin for my domains. I have a new phone. How do I get a new QR for Google Authenticator.

I've been clicking around and don't see it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to log in and add a new device. You can't change the code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a G Suite admin thing, any user can do it:

1. Log into Chrome, click your user icon in the top right corner, Manage your Google Account.
2. Go to Security, 2-Step Verification, sign in and click SET UP under Authenticator app, select your phone.